# adding object key and value to URL Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, pushstate

I have a function which updates the URL query string. in some scenarios it works fine where i have single key and array of values but when i have multiple keys with array of values it doesn't append it to query string but if I see the object i can see the keys and its value. Following is my function

```
function Querystring(obj) {
var querystring = "";
// Build the query string
var currentQueryString = parseQueryString();
var newQueryString = "";
var dataCategory = Object.keys(obj)[0];
console.log(dataCategory);
// Set the new value
if (obj[dataCategory] != null) {
    currentQueryString[dataCategory] = obj[dataCategory].join(",");
    // Loop the keys in currentQueryString and contruct new querystring
    Object.keys(currentQueryString).forEach(function (key, index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            newQueryString += "?" + key + "=" + currentQueryString[key];
        } else {
            newQueryString += "&" + key + "=" + currentQueryString[key];
        }
    });
}
var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + newQueryString;

window.history.pushState({ path: newurl }, '', newurl);

return newQueryString;
```

}

This is how i am calling this function

```
$('.select').change(function () {
                var SortOrder = $(this).attr("id");
                var SortBy = $(this).data("sortby");
                var obj = {};
                obj[SortOrder] = $(this).val();
                obj[SortBy] = [$('option:selected', this).data("price")];
                Querystring(obj);
            });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simply this quite a bit. Try the example below. Ignore the `getParser` function as it is there just for us to be able to test this code.

```js
function getParser(url) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  return a;
}  

function getUpdatedURL(url, newQueryParams) {
  var searchParams = url.search.substring(1).split("&");
  var obj = {};
  searchParams.forEach(function(param){
    var paramParts = param.split("=");
    obj[paramParts[0]] = paramParts[1];
  });
  obj = Object.assign(obj, newQueryParams);
  url.search = "?"+Object.keys(obj).map(p => p+"="+obj[p]).join("&");
  return url.href;
}

var url = getParser("http://example.com/test/page?blah=abc&test=123"); 

//Ignore this as this is just for us to be able to test and run this example. You'll pass in the window.location instead of the url variable defined here.
console.log(getUpdatedURL(url, { sortOrder: "1345", sortBy: ["price","other","more"] }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing code for it is quiet easy, but to get the full juices, i recommend using this tiny library:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

i wrote my own code to build and destruct a query string, but i switched to this one as it gives the full rainbow.

## Usage

```
const queryString = require('query-string');

console.log(location.search);
//=> '?foo=bar' 

const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
console.log(parsed);
//=> {foo: 'bar'} 

console.log(location.hash);
//=> '#token=bada55cafe' 

const parsedHash = queryString.parse(location.hash);
console.log(parsedHash);
//=> {token: 'bada55cafe'} 

parsed.foo = 'unicorn';
parsed.ilike = 'pizza';

const stringified = queryString.stringify(parsed);
//=> 'foo=unicorn&ilike=pizza' 

location.search = stringified;
// note that `location.search` automatically prepends a question mark 
console.log(location.search);
//=> '?foo=unicorn&ilike=pizza'
```